# A file path for local cache in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis

On desktop applications I would use application.startuppath & "\whatever.dat" but this isn't available in asp.net.

If I wanted to create some temporary files during runtime for read/write, how would I get a path that would be Ok in a shared hosting environment?

Using a database like mysql is not an option for this, too slow.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the appsettings feature. This is defined in web.config. (in the configuration section).

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="StartUpPath" value="\whatever.dat" />
</appSettings>
```

And then in your code you can use:

```
string myFilePath = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["StartUpPath"];
```

Don't forget to include System.Configuration.